# Is it possible to cross-compile C++ applications from Linux for Windows XP?

Tags: c++, mingw, windows-xp

I have a simple console application which I already ported to Windows. I also cross-compile it using mingw. However the problem is applications compiled like this only run on Windows Vista or newer. How would I go about compiling it for XP using Linux? Also, I don't know if this is necessary, but here are my compiler flags:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres src/icon.rc src/icon.o
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o cli-mg-64bit-windows.exe src/main.cpp src/icon.o -static
i686-w64-mingw32-windres src/icon.rc src/icon.o
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -o cli-mg-32bit-windows.exe src/main.cpp src/icon.o -static
```

Comment: Why do you need winxp support? The only option is to find a sufficiently old MinGW, maybe even run a Windows version with Wine.

Comment: It's almost certainly *possible*, but finding out how to do it is another matter.

Comment: I would expect getting an older version of MinGW installed on your linux OS would be a solution provided your code does not require modern c++

Comment: Where can I find old versions of MinGW for Arch Linux? Also, would mt19937 functions work using and older version?

Comment: `mt19937` is from C++11. XP is from 2001. That's a bit of a gap. It's not that `mt19937` needs OS support, it's just that there's a 10 year window in which MinGW could target XP but not know about C++11. But seriously? XP has been End Of Life for a decade.

Comment: I wanted to support XP because I wanted to use the program on my retro PC which I use for running old software mostly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to use a version of MinGW-w64 that was built with `configure` flags `--with-default-msvcrt=msvcrt-os` and `--with-default-win32-winnt=0x0501`.

These flags will result in MinGW-w64 libraries that will only use Windows features available up to Windows XP.

For a list of values and their corresponding Windows version see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/modifying-winver-and-win32-winnt